# AjaxControlToolkit Calendar postioning relative to popup image and not the textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I am using an AjaxControlToolkit Calander control. But as per my requirements I have to split the selected date into separate textboxes for date month and year. So I have used a textbox say "textbox1" which have an popupimage button for the ajax control calander.

I make the textBox1 hidden with css and have autopostback set to true. On the text change event I split the date string and put it in separate textboxes as desired.

Everything is working fine except for the positioning of the Calander control. When I hide the main textbox control the calander positions itself on the top left side of the screen and not near the popimage. How can I fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer above just a slight modification is needed to make it the correct answer.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" style="border:0 none       Transparent;margin:0;width:0;background-color:Transparent"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

It will surely have an abnormal behavior if you try to attach a calendar control on a hidden TextBox. Instead of hiding the textbox, make it look like hidden but not literally hidden.
for example

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" style="border:0 none Transparent;margin:0;width:0;background-color:Transparent" ReadOnly="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I finally did.

Comment: Only one change is required in the above solution and that is ReadOnly="false". Otherwise the textchange event wont fire.